# Get details of all the Markers covered under a drawn polygon or any shape using react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, marker, react-google-maps

I am using react-google-maps. I have created map and displayed 3 types of markers in it. 
I can now draw polygons on map but not able to get the details of markers covered under the drawn shape. 
Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code of map jsx.
I am creating 3 different markers with different icons to identify on map.
When i draw a shape on map, i want to get the details of every sort of marker which comes under the drawn shape.

```
import React from "react";
import DrawingManager from "react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager";
import {GoogleMap, InfoWindow, Marker, withGoogleMap, withScriptjs} from "react-google-maps";
import UploadApis from "../../service/rest/upload";
import "./index.scss";

let selectedShape;

function clearSelection() {
    if (selectedShape) {
        if (selectedShape.type !== 'marker') {
            selectedShape.setEditable(false);
        }
        selectedShape = null;
    }
}

function setSelection(shape) {
    if (shape.type !== 'marker') {
        clearSelection();
        shape.setEditable(true);
    }
    selectedShape = shape;
}

class Map extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.shapes = [];
        this.state = {
            fiberData: [],
            subscriberData: [],
            sitesData: [],
            fetchData: false,
            selected: null
        };
        this.handleOverlayComplete = this.handleOverlayComplete.bind(this);
        this.data();
    }

    handleOverlayComplete(e) {
        console.log("overlay",e);
        const newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;

        if (e.type !== window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            window.google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
                if (e.vertex !== undefined) {
                    if (newShape.type === window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
                        let path = newShape.getPaths().getAt(e.path);
                        path.removeAt(e.vertex);
                        if (path.length < 3) {
                            newShape.setMap(null);
                        }
                    }
                    if (newShape.type === window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
                        let path = newShape.getPath();
                        path.removeAt(e.vertex);
                        if (path.length < 2) {
                            newShape.setMap(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                setSelection(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
        } else {
            window.google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
                setSelection(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
        }
        this.shapes.push(newShape);
    }


    data = async () => {
        let fiberData = await UploadApis.getMetaDataById("fiber",this.props.projectId);
        let sitesData = await UploadApis.getMetaDataById("sites",this.props.projectId);
        let subscriberData = await UploadApis.getMetaDataById("subscriber",this.props.projectId);

        this.setState({fiberData: fiberData, sitesData: sitesData, subscriberData: subscriberData, fetchData: true})
    };

    deleteSelectedShape = () => {
        if (selectedShape) {
            selectedShape.setMap(null);
        }
    };

    setSelected(selected) {
        this.setState({selected: selected})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="btn-container" onClick={this.deleteSelectedShape}>Delete Shape
                </button>
                {this.state.fetchData ?
                    <div>
                        <GoogleMap
                            defaultZoom={6}
                            defaultCenter={{lat: 22.5106879, lng: 79.9189213}}
                        >
                            <DrawingManager
                                defaultDrawingMode={null}
                                defaultOptions={{
                                    drawingControl: true,
                                    drawingControlOptions: {
                                        position: window.google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                                        drawingModes: [ 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']

                                    },
                                    polygonOptions: {editable: true},
                                    circleOptions: {editable: true},
                                    rectangleOptions: {editable: true},
                                    markerOptions: {editable: true},
                                    polylineOptions: {editable: true}
                                }}
                                onOverlayComplete={this.handleOverlayComplete}

                            />

                            {this.state.fiberData.map((fiber) => (
                                <Marker
                                    key={fiber.id}
                                    position={{lat: fiber.latitude, lng: fiber.longitude}}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        this.setSelected(fiber);
                                    }}
                                    icon={{
                                        url: "../assets/svg/fiber.png",
                                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                                    }}
                                />
                            ))}

                            {this.state.sitesData.map((site) => (
                                <Marker
                                    key={site.id}
                                    position={{lat: site.latitude, lng: site.longitude}}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        this.setSelected(site);
                                    }}
                                    icon={{
                                        url: "../assets/svg/tower.png",
                                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                                    }}
                                />
                            ))}

                            {this.state.subscriberData.map((subscriber) => (
                                <Marker
                                    key={subscriber.id}
                                    position={{lat: subscriber.latitude, lng: subscriber.longitude}}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        this.setSelected(subscriber);
                                    }}
                                    icon={{
                                        url: "../assets/svg/subscriber.svg",
                                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                                    }}
                                />
                            ))}

                            {this.state.selected && (
                                <InfoWindow
                                    position={{lat: this.state.selected.latitude, lng: this.state.selected.longitude}}
                                    onCloseClick={() => {
                                        this.setSelected(null);
                                    }}>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>{this.state.selected.name}</h4>
                                        <p>{this.state.selected.description}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </InfoWindow>
                            )}
                        </GoogleMap>
                    </div> : null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
```

This is the first file which i have called. Index file which renders the map is -

````
import React from "react";
import Map from './map.jsx';

export default class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    _projectId="";

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);

        if(props.location.state.project){
            this._projectId = props.location.state.project.id;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Map
                    googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=API_KEY`}
                    loadingElement={<div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
                    containerElement={<div style={{height: `480px`}}/>}
                    mapElement={<div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
                    projectId ={this._projectId}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}```
````

Comment: sscce.org please

Comment: added more details